# user defined class as a property ios

Tags: ios, objective-c

i have a class file, say **Vehicle** ,that initializes another object ,say **Car**. Now i want the car object to be accessed outside by another class.
Is it a good practice to define Class Car as a property in the Vehicle Class and then access it ? Or is there another better approach?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It make no sense to me. `Car` is a _kind of_ `Vehicle`, which indicate subcalss relationship. but what you doing is saying `Car` is _part of_ `Vehicle`.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. there is no relation between the two objects. you may interpret it as Class A and Class B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that would be the correct approach if you want the instance of your `Car` class to essentially be owned by `Vehicle`. You would do something like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Car;

@interface Vehicle : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) Car *myCar;

@end
```

Like you said, you end up with a class `Vehicle` which has a property of type `Car` (which must be initialized) that you can access outside of the `Vehicle` class.

Comment: No problem. Just keep in mind that like Bryan Chen said in the comments, if `Car` inherits from `Vehicle`, you shouldn't use a setup like this.

Comment: yeah i agree with both of you'll . my bad in selecting the wrong example.